# WPF binding datatemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, itemscontrol

Im a new WPF and Im doing about MVVM. My problem is as follows: first I have 1 ObservableCollection. Here contains a list of my information. And I also make it an Icommand in the HomeViewModel so that it can bind to my button in the datatemplate.

In the View I have a xaml file that gets the datacontext from the HomeViewModel. And I can only bind the values ​​in ObservableCollection or Icommand in ItemsSou[enter image description here][1]rce. But I want both . Maybe it's because my code logic is wrong but can anyone help me please.

here is the snippet of my ViewModel:

```
public class HomeViewModel: BaseViewModel
    {
        public ICommand AddCommand { get; set; }
        public ICommand ChangeHomeBG { get; set; }
        public ICommand LookBill { get; set; }

        #region Khoi tao 
        private ObservableCollection<OderModel> oderviewmodel;
        public ObservableCollection<OderModel> OderViewModel
        {
            get
            {
                if (oderviewmodel == null)
                {
                    oderviewmodel = new ObservableCollection<OderModel>();
                }
                return oderviewmodel;
            }
            set
            {
                oderviewmodel = value;
                //OnpropertyChanged(nameof(OderViewModel)); 
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(OderViewModel));

            }
        }
        public HomeViewModel()
        {
            //Khởi tạo dữ liệu-vui lòng không làm quá nhiều tác vụ ở đây, bạn có thể sử dụng Tác vụ nếu cần
            oderviewmodel = new ObservableCollection<OderModel>();
            //oderviewmodel.Add(new OderModel { Name = "Meme", TenBan = "A8" });
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                oderviewmodel.Add(new OderModel { ID = "#00234", Status = "Đang phục vụ", SoNguoi = 8, TenBan = "A8", Price = Utils.ConvertMoney("100000"), Time = "3 Giờ 34 phút" });
            }

            LookBill = new RelayCommand<Window>((p) => { return true; }, (p) => MessageBox.Show("helo br"));

            //AddCommand = new DelegateCommand<string>(
            //    (s) => true, 
            //    (s) => OderViewModel.Add(new OderModel { ID = s})
            //    );
        }
}
```

here is the snippet of my View:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="OderViewModel" ItemsSource="{Binding OderViewModel}"  ScrollBar.Scroll="ItemsControl_Scroll">
                <ItemsControl.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ItemsControl">
                        <Border>
                            <ItemsPresenter/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.Template>

                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <!--<DataTemplate.Resources>
                        <Style>
                            -->
                        <!--Style in template-->
                        <!--
                        </Style>
                    </DataTemplate.Resources>-->
                        <Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" Margin="15,0,0,15">
                            <Grid Width="186" Height="150">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="30*"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="90*"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="30*"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                <Grid x:Name="HedearCardHome"  Grid.Row="0" Background="{DynamicResource StatusColorHome }">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="53*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="90*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="43*"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DataContext.ID }"
                                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                           FontSize="12"
                                           Foreground="White"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                    <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Status}"
                                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                           Foreground="White"
                                           FontSize="12"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                    <Grid Grid.Column="2">
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SoNguoi}"
                                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                           VerticalAlignment="Center"   
                                           Foreground="White"
                                           FontSize="12" Margin="25,0,0,0"/>
                                        <fa:FontAwesome Icon="User" 
                                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                    FontSize="12"
                                                    Foreground="White"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid x:Name="ContentHeaderHome" Grid.Row="1" Background="White">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="55"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="131"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                    <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                                        <Image Source="{StaticResource Hline}"
                                           HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding TenBan}"
                                               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                               FontWeight="Bold"
                                               FontSize="35"
                                               Foreground="{DynamicResource StatusColorHome}"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                    <!--<Border BorderBrush="#F2F1F1" BorderThickness="0.3" >
                                    
                                </Border>-->
                                    <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition/>
                                            <RowDefinition/>
                                            <RowDefinition/>
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                                            <Image Source="{DynamicResource Hline}"
                                               VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                               HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                                <Image.LayoutTransform>
                                                    <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
                                                </Image.LayoutTransform>

                                            </Image>


                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Price}"
                                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                   FontSize="26"
                                                   FontWeight="Bold"
                                                   Foreground="{DynamicResource StatusColorHome}">

                                            </TextBlock>
                                        </Grid>
                                        <Grid Grid.Row="2">
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                                                <fa:FontAwesome Icon="ClockOutline" 
                                                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                            Foreground="{DynamicResource GrayTimeHome}"/>

                                            </Grid>
                                            <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Time}"
                                                       FontSize="11"
                                                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                       Foreground="{DynamicResource GrayHome1}"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                            <Grid Grid.Column="3">
                                                <fa:FontAwesome Icon="BirthdayCake"
                                                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                            FontSize="12"
                                                            Foreground="{DynamicResource StatusColorHome}"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid x:Name="FooterHome" Grid.Row="2" Background="{DynamicResource FooterHome}">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                                        <Button x:Name="btn_HomeBill" 
                                                Background="{DynamicResource FooterHome}" 
                                                BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Command="{Binding LookBill}">
                                            <Image Source="{StaticResource lookbill}"  VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                        </Button>
                                    </Grid>
                                    <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                                        <Button Background="{DynamicResource FooterHome}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}">
                                            <Image Source="{StaticResource iconPrint}"  VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                        </Button>
                                    </Grid>
                                    <Grid Grid.Column="2">
                                        <StackPanel>
                                            <Button Background="{DynamicResource FooterHome}" 
                                                    BorderBrush="{x:Null}" 
                                                    Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.LookBill}" 
                                                    CommandParameter="{Binding}" 
                                                    Margin="0,0,0,-2">

                                                <Image Source="{StaticResource iconMoney}"  VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >

                                                </Image>
                                            </Button>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </Grid>
                                    <!--<Grid Grid.Column="3">
                                    <fa:FontAwesome Icon="EllipsisH"
                                                    FontSize="20"
                                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                    Foreground="{DynamicResource IconFooter}"/>
                                </Grid>-->
                                    <Grid Grid.Column="3">
                                        <materialDesign:PopupBox Foreground="{DynamicResource IconFooter}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                            <StackPanel>
                                                <Button Content="More"/>
                                                <Button Content="Option"/>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </materialDesign:PopupBox>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
```

here is the snippet I want to Change:(ItemSource)

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="OderViewModel" ItemsSource="{Binding OderViewModel}"  ScrollBar.Scroll="ItemsControl_Scroll">
```

And Here why im not binding Icommand in button ?

```
<Grid Grid.Column="0">
                                        <Button x:Name="btn_HomeBill" 
                                                Background="{DynamicResource FooterHome}" 
                                                BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Command="{Binding LookBill}">
                                            <Image Source="{StaticResource lookbill}"  VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                        </Button>
                                    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `btn_HomeBill` button is inside your ItemsControl.ItemTemplate. This means that its DataContext is `OderModel` and no longer `HomeViewModel` where you have access to `LookBill`.

You should be able to change the binding to this:

```xml
<Button x:Name="btn_HomeBill"
        ...
        Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}, Path=DataContext.LookBill}" />
```

Comment: So if i have more button and more Icommand . what should i do?